# Can't set gsettings due to missing glibxcc?

Tags: gnome

I'm on a fresh install of Ubuntu22 and trying to run `gsettings set org.gnome.mutter check-alive-timeout 500000`. This raises:

```
/snap/core20/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproxy.so.1)
Failed to load module: /home/alexander/snap/code/common/.cache/gio-modules/libgiolibproxy.so
```

I'd appreciate a description of how to fix this with at least a surface level explanation if possible (google pulls up quick fixes to related problems but I don't like the idea of just copy pasting them into my terminal without understanding).

Comment: What is the output of `which gsettings`? Does your command work if you use `/usr/bin/gsettings` instead of `gsettings`, i.e. `/usr/bin/gsettings set org.gnome.mutter check-alive-timeout 500000`?

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog the output of `which gsettings` is `/usr/bin/gsettings`. So it follows that trying your suggestion gives the same error.

Comment: Have you set an `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` pointing to `/snap/core20/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` by any chance?

Comment: @steeldriver just tried this and the "Failed to load module" error disappears. but the first line `gsettings: /snap/core20/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by gsettings)` is still there.

Comment: @AlexanderSoare I was not intending you to set it, I was asking to check if it was already set (e.g. `declare -p LD_LIBRARY_PATH`) - what happens if you **un**set any such variable (`unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH`)?

Comment: @steeldriver thought so, just didn't want to waste a comment cycle in case I was wrong :) Anyway, it was already not set in the first place. I tried unsetting it  again just to doubly confirm. The result is the same as described in my OP.

Comment: OK so if it's not being introduced by LD_LIBRARY_PATH, could there be a snap path in an ld.so.conf.d file (`grep -r snap /etc/ld.so.conf.d/`)?

Comment: @steeldriver the output of that grep is nothing.